# How to keep these conditionals DRY

Tags: javascript

I've got a very long conditional statement that's repeated many times in a function.

```
if (a === b) {
  const c = ...
  const d = ...
  ...
  c.forEach(() => {
    ...
  });
  // more stuff
} else if (a !== b) {
  const c = ...
  const d = ...
  ...
  c.forEach(() => {
    ...
  });
  // more stuff
}
```

How best to keep this DRY?

Comment: use a function?

Comment: Be more specific. It seems that you overly simplified the actual problem.

Comment: So refactor the common stuff out into a method and call the method....

Comment: It doesn't cut out much code, but your `else if (a !== b)` here is the same as just `else`

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom function tyo avoid repeating the same code. Whichever you feel repeating just move it a function and call the function by passing the data to it.

```
customFunction(c, d){
     //do whatever you want here
     c.forEach(item => {

     });
}

if (a === b) {
   customFunction(arg1, arg2);
} else{
   customFunction(arg1, arg2);
}
```